# Node js webpack command is not working

Tags: webpack

Hello I am using webpack and when I run 'webpack entry bundle.js', it generates this error message

```
Version: webpack 4.16.3
Time: 596ms
Built at: 2018-07-27 06:43:09
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] multi ./script1.js ./bundle.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./script1.js 192 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

ERROR in multi ./script1.js ./bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './bundle.js' in 'C:\Users\...\webpack_'
 @ multi ./script1.js ./bundle.js main[1]

ERROR in ./script1.js 1:34
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:34)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> var message = require('./script2'):
|
| alert(message);
 @ multi ./script1.js ./bundle.js main[0]
```

I have put all files on the same folder.

script1.js file

```
var message = require('./script2'):
alert(message);
```

script2.js file

```
module.exports  = "hello";
```

thanks

Comment: This is a simple typo: change the colon at the end of line 1 in script1.js to a semicolon and you are good to go

Comment: I have changed it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Still the same error message?

Comment: yes it is still

Answer (score 2):

Now I got it.
put the entry point in `./src` folder and add this code below in `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --mode development ./src/index.js --output ./bundle.js",
  "build": "webpack --mode production ./src/index.js --output ./bundle.js"
  }
```

then run this `npm run dev` command on the terminal.It works!
for more help visit https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-tutorial